# x not found in 'customNpmPackage' eslint import/named error but is exported

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, tsconfig, typescript-eslint

**Context**

I created a custom npm package with components which I imported in my project. Everything works fine excepts for types and functions where I get this error :

> useWindowDimensions not found in '@espe/components-front' eslint (import/named)

Here is how I import it in my project :

`import { useWindowDimensions } from '@espe/components-front'`

VSCode does find the corresponding function (see screenshot) ->
[VSCode prompt when hovering useWindowDimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMug5.png)

**project/eslintrc.json**

```
{
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:react/jsx-runtime",
        "plugin:import/recommended",
        "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        // must be last:
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "import/parsers": {
            "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
        },
        // Tells eslint how to resolve imports
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "paths": ["src"],
                "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
            },
            "typescript": {}
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "unused-imports"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
        "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "warn",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "warn",
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off",
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run the project I get this error :

> caught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@espe_components-front.js?v=4507f80d' does not provide an export named 'useWindowDimensions'

**Package architecture and export line**

```
- src
  |_ index.ts // export * from './hooks'
  |_ hooks
    |_ index.ts // export * from './useWindowDimensions'
    |_ useWindowDimensions.ts // export const useWindowDimensions = () => { ... }
```

**package/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "DOM.Iterable",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "declarationDir": "dist/types",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/components/index.d.ts"]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

**package/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@espe/components-front",
  "version": "1.0.4",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vite build && tsc"
  },
  "main": "./dist/ap27333-components-front.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/ap27333-components-front.es.js",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/ap27333-components-front.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/ap27333-components-front.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

I tried changing exports to default, various config tweaks in `package/tsconfig.json` based on other stackoverflow issues but could not find a solution.

My guess is that maybe I am exporting the wrong way or that the package config is wrong, does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. It was related to my vite config.

Here is my **package/vite.config.ts**

```
export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    ...,
    build: {
      lib: {
        entry: resolve('src/index.ts'),
        name: 'ap27333-components-front',
        formats: ['es', 'umd'],
        fileName: (format) => `ap27333-components-front.${format}.js`,
      },
    },
  }
})
```

The important part is `entry: resolve('src/index.ts')` where the path was incorrect for me.